# Creating database with EF cannot be opened by ssms (Access denied)

Tags: entity-framework, ssms

I create the Entity DB (if file not exists) in `C:\Temp\MyDB.mdf` using : `MyEFContext.CreateDatabase()`.

I can open the DB with VS Express 2010 and navigate through it but when attempting to adding (Joining) the DB in SSMS i get the following error : `Unable to open the physical file "C:\Temp\MyDB.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)`

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rights issue.

In the case where it works you are in the user context of the user account that you logged in with.

In the case where it does not work, it is the user account that the SQL server is running under that is trying to access the file.

Check which account SQL server is using, then give that account access to the files on the temp directory.